# Don't want to save credentials when login through react native app

Tags: react-native

I am developing a react native mobile app in which I am login through microsoft and for that I have used WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync('') to open microsoft login window and after entering the credentials my app works correctly but after logging out when I again try to log in it doesn't ask for credentials, as it by default saved the credentials and if I want to enter with other account I have to delete the history from chrome.
Can anyone tell me how to deal with this situation and how to allow browser not to save credentials by default.